# java.io.FileInputStream accesses private volatile variable 'closed' only from inside synchronized block. Why?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile, happens-before

As far as I know, 'happens-before' states that changes made inside synchronized are visible to next thread, synchronizing on the same lock.

```
private final Object closeLock = new Object();
private volatile boolean closed = false;

public void close() throws IOException {
    synchronized (closeLock) {
        if (closed) {
            return;
        }
        closed = true;
    }
    if (channel != null) {
       channel.close();
    }

    fd.closeAll(new Closeable() {
        public void close() throws IOException {
           close0();
       }
    });
}
```

Isn't it redundant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronization makes two different guarantees in Java: visibility and atomicity. Making the variable `volatile` guarantees that the JVM will ensure visibility of writes properly follow "happens-before", but does not guarantee that the check-then-act within the synchronized block is atomic.

Without the guarantee of atomicity, thread interleaving on that sequence of `if (closed) return; closed = true;` could result in some synchronization issues.

If the variable is always accessed from within synchronized blocks on the same monitor, the `volatile` is not necessary, but might have some other minor performance impact.

Comment: Any performance impact would be negative, though, would it not?

Comment: @jaco0646 My intended implication was that I am not aware of a performance gain or loss when combining volatile and synchronized blocks for file I/O. I assume this code has been this way for some time, not having tracked the history of the file. Since there are ways to contribute back to the java codebase, I also assume that if it were a major performance loss it would have been discovered and corrected at some point. Regardless, the performance consequence is out of the scope of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

The variable is likely accessed by the native methods. You'll need to look at the native source code for the JDK.

Comment: Does `volatile` make guarantees regarding native method access?

Comment: That's a good question. Apparently it is not guaranteed (but this code is part of the JDK and thus can make implementation specific assumptions): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130487/jni-java-thread-safe-publishing-sharing-of-effectively-immutable-native-object

Answer (score 1):

The `volatile` keyword is redundant, according to the second bullet point of [Memory Consistency Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility).

> An unlock (synchronized block or method exit) of a monitor
>   *happens-before* every subsequent lock (synchronized block or method
>   entry) of that same monitor. And because the *happens-before* relation
>   is transitive, all actions of a thread prior to unlocking
>   *happen-before* all actions subsequent to any thread locking that
>   monitor.